# Wedding, menstruation, and the mikvah. What does one do?

Tags: wedding, mikvah-ritual-bath

When does a bride go to the mikveh for her wedding? Need it be before, or can it be after? What if she thinks that she will still be bleeding at the wedding?

What sources are there that provide guidance on this?

I appreciate your insight, and I hope other women will as well.

Thank you.

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%A6%D7%91_%D7%91

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Menstruating on Wedding Day](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68290/menstruating-on-wedding-day)

Answer (score 3):

[Nishmat's Women’s Health and Halacha site](http://www.yoatzot.org/home/) is a good source for *halacha* for women's health, and they also answer individual questions. Regarding your question, [they write](http://www.yoatzot.org/life-cycle/default.asp?id=640)

> To avoid a number of problems (see below), it is strongly recommended
>   that the wedding be scheduled for a date when the bride will not be
>   *niddah*. She should choose a date at least one week after she expects all bleeding to have ceased, allowing her enough time to count seven
>   blood-free days and then immerse in the *mikveh* before the wedding.
>   (Unlike a married woman, a bride does not need to wait five days from
>   the onset of her menses, but may perform the *hefsek taharah* as soon
>   as she stops bleeding.) But, since it is impossible to predict
>   menstruation exactly, it is best to set the wedding date somewhat
>   later than this minimum.

However practically, if the wedding is set long in advance, or cycles
somewhat irregular,

> or the excitement and stress surrounding the
>   wedding [might] lead to an irregular cycle. Therefore, many brides
>   take hormones to regulate their cycles, even if they normally
>   menstruate regularly.

and from [here](http://www.yoatzot.org/life-cycle/default.asp?id=646)

> If a bride is *niddah* at her wedding, the ceremony is valid but certain
>   problems arise. First, of course, the couple may not consummate the
>   marriage until she is able to immerse in the *mikveh*, and they must
>   observe all the restrictions (*harchakot*) concerning not touching,
>   etc., applicable to a regular *niddah*. Moreover, the newlyweds may not
>   even be left alone together, particularly at night.